# Primefaces 4 commandButton oncomplete giving error PF(...).show is not a function

Tags: java, primefaces

I have the panel below and when the page loads, it looks like this:
[image]

When you click a user in a table that's not shown, the panel updates and looks like this:
[image]

Then when I click the "Add/Remove Groups" button, I would expect the picklist to appear, but instead I see the error in my firebug console:
[image]

What is wrong here?

```
<p:panel id="userDetails" header="User Details" styleClass="panels-right" visible="#{groupBacking.currentTable == 'Users'}">
        <ui:fragment rendered="#{groupBacking.selectedUser != null}">
            <p:commandButton value="Add/Remove Groups" styleClass="ui-priority-primary" actionListener="#{groupBacking.populateGroupPicklist}" oncomplete="PF('groupPicklistWidget').show()" />

            <strong>User Id: </strong> <h:outputText value="#{groupBacking.selectedUser.ccsId}" /><br />
            <strong>First Name: </strong> <h:outputText value="#{groupBacking.selectedUser.firstName}" /><br />
            <strong>Last Name: </strong> <h:outputText value="#{groupBacking.selectedUser.lastName}" /><br />
            <strong>Active: </strong> <h:outputText value="#{groupBacking.selectedUser.active}" /><br />
            <strong>Groups: </strong> 
            <ui:repeat var="group" value="#{groupBacking.selectedUser.groups}">
                <h:outputText value="#{group.name}" /><br />
            </ui:repeat>
        </ui:fragment>

        <p:pickList widgetVar="groupPicklistWidget" id="groupPicklist" style="display: none;" value="#{groupBacking.picklistGroups}" var="group" 
                    itemLabel="#{group.name}" itemValue="#{group.name}" showSourceFilter="true" showTargetFilter="true" filterMatchMode="contains">
            <f:facet name="available">Available</f:facet>
            <f:facet name="assigned">Assigned</f:facet>

            <p:ajax event="transfer" listener="#{groupBacking.onGroupTransfer}" update=":growl" />
        </p:pickList>

        <ui:fragment rendered="#{groupBacking.selectedUser == null}">
            <h:outputText value="Click a user to see their details" />
        </ui:fragment>
</p:panel>
```

Comment: Just to be sure. The dialog is rendered in the hmtl page? And the widgetVar is assigned correctly?

Comment: There is no dialog. I'm just trying to make a picklist appear/disappear when that button is clicked and after my actionlistener on the button finishes.

Comment: Sorry i meant the picklist, not the dialog. And you are sure that you are using PF4 and not PF3.X? Take a look at the html page and check (Firebug or something else) if the widgetvar assignment to the picklist was correctly.

Answer (score 0):

Primefaces 4 commandButton oncomplete giving error PF(…).show is not a function

My demo.xhtml is as shown below

```
  <html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml"
    xmlns:ui="http://java.sun.com/jsf/facelets"
    xmlns:h="http://java.sun.com/jsf/html"
    xmlns:f="http://java.sun.com/jsf/core"
    xmlns:c="http://java.sun.com/jstl/core"
    xmlns:p="http://primefaces.org/ui">

<h:form id="demoForm">

   <p:commandButton id="hiddenSaveButton" value="AddRomove"
    action="display" oncomplete="duplicateCheckDialog.show()"
    style="float:right;"/>

    <p:dialog id="dialog" header="Account Creation" 
     widgetVar="duplicateCheckDialog" resizable="true"
 showEffect="bounce" hideEffect="fold" dynamic="true"
     appendToBody="false" >
 <div style="width: 100%" align="center">     
 <h:panelGrid id="display" columns="1" cellpadding="4">
 <div style="float: left; width: 300px;">
 <p:row>
 <h:outputLabel value="Account No. already exists.
     Please enter new Account No"  style="font-weight: bold"/>
 </p:row>
 <p:row>
 <p:commandButton id="backButton" title="Back"  action="backPage"
 value="Back" update=":demoForm:dialog" />
 </p:row>
   </div>
  </h:panelGrid>
   </div>
  </p:dialog>
 </h:form>
</html>
```

Note: In Above Example i have given widget var id to that command button tag.
      you can directly call `oncomplete="duplicateCheckDialog.show()"`. PF is not required

Answer (score 0):

I think the picklist doesn't has show function. If you want to show picklist can you use in dialog. In this case the commandButton call `groupDialogWidget` in oncomplete/onclick method. The example code is below:

```
 <p:commandButton value="Add/Remove Groups" styleClass="ui-priority-primary" actionListener="#{testManagedBean.populateGroupPicklist}" onclick="groupDialogWidget.show();"/>
```

(...)

```
<p:dialog modal="true" showEffect="fade" hideEffect="fade" widgetVar="groupDialogWidget">
     <p:pickList widgetVar="groupPicklistWidget" id="groupPicklist" value="#{testManagedBean.picklistGroups}" var="group"
                                itemLabel="#{group.name}" itemValue="#{group.name}" showSourceFilter="true" showTargetFilter="true" filterMatchMode="contains">
                        <f:facet name="available">Available</f:facet>
                        <f:facet name="assigned">Assigned</f:facet>


     </p:pickList>
</p:dialog>
```

If your purpose is simple hide picketlist you can use simple boolean in your bean. This boolean can you set true/false when user click to button. Here is relevant code for picketlist:

```
style= "#{testManagedBean.showPicketlist eq true ? 'display: block' : 'display: none'}"
```